# how to make pandas read_csv parse dates correctly from its own csv generated file?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following very simple pandas dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [pd.datetime(2015,02,02)]})     

df
Out[53]: 
           A
0 2015-02-02
```

Here, the format of the time variable `A` is a `datetime64`:

```
df.dtypes
Out[54]: 
A    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Now, I save this dataframe as a csv, and load it using `read_csv()` with the `parse_dates` option.

```
df.to_csv('P:test.csv')

df2=pd.read_csv('P:test.csv',parse_dates='A')

df2.dtypes
Out[59]: 
Unnamed: 0     int64
A             object
dtype: object
```

The parser does not recognize the date, so I need to manually run `to_datetime` again (its a loss of time)...

There should be a way to make Pandas parse correctly the date Pandas *itself* generated, right? What is wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: The documentation for `read_csv` states that *parse_dates : boolean, list of ints or names, list of lists, or dict*, i.e. it should be `['A']` instead of `'A'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify a list of column names:

```
parse_dates=['A']
```

Example:

```
>>> pd.read_csv('date.csv', parse_dates=['A']).dtypes
Unnamed: 0             int64
A             datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1)
memory usage: 24.0 bytes
```